# Calcium oxide in self-heating packs

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, heat

I've read some articles on the internet about self-heating meals. Heat released from an exothermic reaction is used to heat up the food. In fact, several reactions are recommended for this purpose including the dissolution of calcium oxide $\ce{CaO}$ in water. However, after doing some experiments, I've got into some problems with this method.

$\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ as a product is only slightly soluble in water. Therefore, the reaction stopped quickly after adding water as the remaining reactant is covered by this insoluble compound.

I've tried **using acids to dissolve insoluble $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$**. This method seems to be effective firsthand. However, *choosing which types of acid* that best fit this situation turned out to be a dilemma. As the pack is in white powder, solid form, some popular strong acid like $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$ as liquids are not suitable. Other weak organic acids are also not considered as the corresponding calcium salts hardly dissolve into water.

My questions are:

1. I've heard that metals like Al, Mg and Fe are added also, however what is the function of these in the mixture with CaO? Absolutely Al can react with $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ but this seems to be slow and therefore not the main reason as it cannot explain in case of Mg and Fe.
2. Is there any proper methods that is used in the commercialized, $\ce{CaO}$-based flameless heater? I feel like my approach is rather unpractical and somewhat expensive if it is formulated to an industrial scale.

Comment: Use fine CaO powder, or add some vinegar to water.

Comment: $1$) $\ce{CaO}$ expands when reacting with water. $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ does not cover $\ce{CaO}$, and  does not prevent new water from getting in touch with "deeper" $\ce{CaO}$. $2$) The best way to dissolve $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ is a  $\ce{HCl}$ solution. Why don't you want it ?

Comment: Not sure if this is used commercially, due to the danger of the reactants. For example, concentrated HCl would be a hazard, and dilute HCl would "draw off" too much heat, as the added water absorbs the energy. Same with acetic acid - vinegar is only5 or 6%, so you'd have a lot of water, and glacial acetic acid is hazardous.

Answer (score 0):

If soluble products are what you want, try one mole of magnesium oxide (which is more stable in typical environments than calcium oxide) to two moles sodium bisulfate. These react to give sodium and magnesium sulfates, which are both soluble, and no gases. Excess sodium bisulfate may improve solubility (by buffering against magnesium hydroxide formation) but may make the solution about as acidic as vinegar.